# Parallel generator destinations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, yield

I am looking for the way to implement a memory-efficient routine to fill two pandas DataFrames in one pass (yet, my question is not about pandas, the thing is that DataFrames seem to be much more efficient in constructing themselves from the generators, than by externally concatenating entries).

I have a hand-written extension that gets the entries from a large file. Each entry is composed from a "vector part" and (one or more) "tabular part(s)". A representative mocking sample with single "table part" would be like

```py
data = [
    ((101, 102), [               (0.1, 11, 2), (0.2, 12, 3) ]),
    ((102, 103), [ (0.3, 21, 1), (0.4, 22, 2), (0.5, 23, 3) ]),
    ((105, 106), [                             (0.6, 32, 3) ])
    # ...
]
```

I would like to have two generators that I can pass into a DataFrame constructors that will yield two sequences: one composed of "vector part" (3x2 in the mock example), line by line and other being composed from individual entries in the table (6x3 in the mock example):

[image: Vector dataframe] [image: Table dataframe]

The most important thing is that I want to produce them in one go. The snippet below could depict the expected result in some way, except for that essential part that this code just prints the lines instead of forwarding them to the generators provided to DataFrame constructors.

```py
def dispatch_data(data, cVect, cTable):
    cVect.send(None)
    cTable.send(None)
    for vect, table in data:
        cVect.send(vect)
        for line in table:
            cTable.send(line)

def connector():
    while True:
        datum = (yield)
        print(datum)
        #yield datum

c1, c2 = connector(), connector()
#df1, df2 = pd.DataFrame(c1), pd.FataFrame(c2)
dispatch_data(data, c1, c2)
```

If one will uncomment the commented lines, this script falls into infinite loop for obvious reason that both `yield`s in `connector()` are released by `send()` calls.

Is it even possible to "split" such dataflow onto two (or more) generators in Python?

---

**Update**

I have found a solution that serves me well right in the sense of not having the threads or complex synchronisation primitives and being severely efficient. Ok, we have a `Queue` here, but it is for greenlets and I found a pretty subtle performance footprint.

It exploits the [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) module and the demo code is actually striking simple:

```py
def dataframe_builder(q):
    def _get_item():
        yield from q
    return pd.DataFrame( _get_item() )

qVect, qTable = gevent.queue.Queue(100)  #< one may tune this values
              , gevent.queue.Queue(1000) #< for best performance

tVect, tTable = gevent.spawn(dataframe_builder, qVect)
              , gevent.spawn(dataframe_builder, qTable)

for vect, table in data:
    qVect.put(vect)
    for line in table:
        qTable.put(line)
qVect.put(StopIteration)
qTable.put(StopIteration)

tVect.join()
tTable.join()
```

Now -- how one can achieve similar result with native Python means? For instance, for many times I met a statement that `gevent` is effectively similar to `asyncio`, so how this scenario might be implemented with `asyncio`? I still see this to be a rather generic and fundamental pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to chunk your data by first handling the creation of the larger "main" table with a pure iterator, and then producing the smaller vector table. This way, only the smaller vector table is loaded into memory, while the larger table is treated entirely as an iterator:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque
def transform_entries(data):
   for a, b in data:
      yield ('vector', a)
      yield from (('table', i) for i in b)

class iter_table:
   def __init__(self, iter_t):
      self.iter_t = iter_t
      self.vector_t, self.flag = deque(), False
   def __iter__(self):
      return self
   def __next__(self):
      if not self.flag:
         while True:
            if (n:=next(self.iter_t, None)) is None:
                self.flag = True
                raise StopIteration
            if n[0] == 'table':
                return n[-1]
            self.vector_t.append(n[-1])
      else:
          if not self.vector_t:
              raise StopIteration
          return self.vector_t.popleft()
             

data = [((101, 102), [(0.1, 11, 2), (0.2, 12, 3)]), ((102, 103), [(0.3, 21, 1), (0.4, 22, 2), (0.5, 23, 3)]), ((105, 106), [(0.6, 32, 3)])]
c = iter_table(transform_entries(data))
df_table, df_vector = pd.DataFrame(c), pd.DataFrame(c)
print(df_table)
print(df_vector)
```

Output:

```
#main table
     0   1  2
0  0.1  11  2
1  0.2  12  3
2  0.3  21  1
3  0.4  22  2
4  0.5  23  3
5  0.6  32  3
#vector table
     0    1
0  101  102
1  102  103
2  105  106
```

Comment: The problem is that the `defaultdict` instance will load the entire `data` in memory first. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid -- the real `data` object is ~10Gb.

Comment: @Crank I added an updated solution that serves as a bit of a tradeoff: the "table part" is treated as a pure iterator since it appears, based on your sample, to consist of the largest portion of the data by far. The "vector table" is the only bit loaded into memory (in `vector_t`), and then is yielded back as well.

Comment: Thank you, @Ajax1234, but it seems to be only a workaround of the problem. I was hoping on somewhat similar to coroutine/async/defer solution since there must be no fundamental restriction on simultaneous iterating over a sub-sequences.
In fact, your approach seems to be technically equivalent to reading both `vect` and `table` into a single dataframe with duplicated `vect` (of 5x6 shape in the example) and then pivoting it over `vect` as index. That is how I do it now, but I believe there must be a more elegant solution.